# How should I write JDBC url for Oracle with LDAP and two LDAP servers?

Tags: java, oracle, url, jdbc, failover

I have an Oracle database with LDAP, and can connect by writing smth like:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://oid0.wow.com:666/chost,cn=OracleContext,dc=wow,dc=com
```

But this is not failover (we have another server with Oracle LDAP - oid1.wow.com:666)

How can I use both servers to reach failover?
I found this [solution](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/urls.htm#CHDBICFA), but it doesn't work:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Invalid LDAP URL specified
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:113)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:147)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:257)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:389)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:454)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:802)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:134)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a driver!

Throw debugging I've found antother issue with String.concat() NPE
Our driver (com.oracle ojdbc14 10.2.0.4.0 - found in MVN repo) doesn't suppor two o more URL's.

When I downloaded driver from Oracle site (10.1.0.5 'ojdbc14_g') all start work fine.

All of this looks strange because 10.1.0.5 seems to be the last version of Oracle JDBC drivers on official site (for Oracle 10 of course).

Here is! Failover dataSource bean:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <!--common dataSource props -->
    <property name="driverClass" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldaps://oid0.wow.com:666/chost,cn=OracleContext,dc=wow,dc=com ldaps://oid1.wow.com:666/chost,cn=OracleContext,dc=wow,dc=com"/>
    <property name="overrideDefaultUser" value="useruser"/>
    <property name="overrideDefaultPassword" value="strongpassword"/>
    <!-- special c3p0 props -->
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="1"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10"/>
    <property name="maxStatements" value="10"/>
    <property name="breakAfterAcquireFailure" value="false"/>
    <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="5"/>
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin" value="true"/>
    <property name="properties">
        <props>
            <prop key="oracle.net.ldap_loadbalance">OFF</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Yes.  Also, if you are using 11g drivers and connecting to OID via LDAPS you need at least version 11.2.0.3 otherwise you will get a NullPointer exception.